# Does SSG in angular allow HTTP request

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

While making use of SSG in angular application, can the components part of the routes set for SSG make API calls? When I try to implement it, I get an error that says `NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken REQUEST!`

A work-around for this is to add `@Optional()` on on the injection a request. But this won't have the desired effect since I would need to make API calls to get language translations for the content of the page (if the endpoint starts with `/fr`).

If SSG is not applicable in this case, is there another way to pre-render the pages while making the initial API call for translations?

Comment: What you mean when you say SSG? Also this is very little information to help you with the error, may be please add some code where you get the error and the error also... And if you are asking whether API calls can be made with server side rendering then yes they very well can be..

Comment: I guess you mean SSR (server side rendering)?

Answer (score 0):

you should navigate to app.config.ts and add the thing you want inside providers list.
I had the same issue with HttpClient which has been solved by adding it in providers list inside the given direction.